# How to delete records after past 14 days in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to delete data before 14 days from current date. for ex. if today is 20 June i want to delete records before 6 june. (may be from 6 june to 1 june)

currently I am doing this but its deleting 14 days past records from today

```
 func removeOldNotifications(_ days: Int) {

    guard let fromSearchDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -14, to: Date()) else {
        return
    }

    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss" // Only Date Fetch No need to check Time
    let fromSearchDateString = dateFormatterGet.string(from: fromSearchDate)
    print("*** Delete From Date String: \(fromSearchDateString)")

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "NotificationTrack")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    let predicaate =  NSPredicate(format: "notificationSendTimeStamp < %@", fromSearchDateString)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicaate

    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

    do {
        try context.execute(deleteRequest)
        try context.save()
        print("Deleted Old Core data objects from Entity ")
    } catch let error {
        print("Detele Old data in error :", error)
    }
}
```

How can i delete before 14 days data?
Delete logic is done only i am getting confused with the setting date.

Comment: How and where are you deleting the records? Show your code.

Comment: @Frankenstein delete thing is done ..i am looking for logic for dates from past 14 days before

Comment: There are infinite dates past 14 days. Are you going to try to delete records for infinite days?

Comment: yes thats what my question is ..is there anything to get atelast 30days past 14 days?

Comment: This doesn't really sound like you've defined the actual issue - deleting records is just noise. Why not ask what you really are looking for? Date ranges. You *may* need to declare *two* variables - one for 14 days ago from today, one for the "beginning of time". But this really sounds (to me) like a pretty "classic" coding question. Am I missing something?

Comment: I recommend to declare the attribute `notificationSendTimeStamp` as `Date`. This is more reliable for comparing dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a Record object that looks like this:

```
struct Record {
    let id: String
    let date: Date
}
```

Your code is correct, if you want to get the date two weeks ago from **now**, you would do the following:

```
let nowDate = Date()
let twoWeeksAgoDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -14, to: nowDate)!
```

Then if you have an array filled with your `Records`, simply filter the old records like so, and return their ids:

```
let toBeRemovedIds = records.filter { $0.date < twoWeeksAgoDate }.map { $0.id }
```

**This will give you all of the ids of the Record that are older than the specified interval** (in your case, two weeks), and now you can simply delete them in your database or wherever they're stored.

Now it all depends on your use case. Since you've said you already know how to handle the deleting process I'm not sure whether your records are CoreData records or anything else, but for example if they were CoreData records indeed, then you would simply add a predicate to your request in order to filter out all the records that match your date range, like so:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date < %@", twoWeeksAgoDate as NSDate)
```

And then again, simply remove the fetched records.

**Edit:**

Your issue is happening because of the predicate you use in your request. I would suggest you to make your `notificationSentDate` property a `Date` instead of a `String` in your **CoreData model**.

This would simply make more sense, and would be way less error prone. Just remember to cast your date object as an NSDate in the predicate. Anyways, the final working method would look like this:

```
func removeNotificationsOlderThan(days: Int) {
    let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = context.persistentStoreCoordinator
    // Calculate the limit date for a record to be valid by using the days parameter of your method:
    let limitDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -days, to: Date())
    // Create a predicate that match this date:
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "notificationSentDate < %@", limitDate as NSDate)
    // Initialize the NSFetchRequest:
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "NotificationTrack")
    // Add the predicate to it:
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    // Initialize your NSBatchDeleteRequest using your fetch request:
    let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    // Perform the delete operation asynchronously:
    privateContext.perform {
        do {
            // Try executing the batch request:
            try privateContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest)
            if privateContext.hasChanges {
                // Reflect the changes if anything changed:
                try privateContext.save()
            }
        }
        catch let error {
            // Handle the error here
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help..I have update question with my remove logic..but its deleting records even before 14 days also..can you please check my logic?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete any record that is between `startDate` and `endDate` like this:

```
let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -44, to: Date())
let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -14, to: Date())
```

Or just invert the delete login and delete all the records before the `endDate` as `Date`s are comparable this won't take much effort.